# Which log will tell me why my computer shut down?

Tags: power-management

I was at school SSHing to my homebox. All of a sudden, my connection was closed. Attempting to reconnect failed. When I returned home, I discovered that my computer was off.

Nobody was at my house and I am sure that I did not have a power outage.

How can I figure out how or why my computer shut off? Is there some log in `/var/log` that could point me in the right direction? Should there be a core dump somewhere that I should find? If so, how do I use core dumps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant files  in `/var/log` are messages, `dmesg`

issue, command `last` to see the exact reboot time.
You will see a line starting with `reboot` (or may be `shutdown`) for  all reboot/crash.
`cat /var/log/messages` from a terminal and check for messages at the time stamp of reboot or just before it.
`dmesg` can give the last boot time messages.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

It is  unusual for a kernel error to shutdown the power, it would either hang with a kernel panic or reboot. It was most likely an hardware issue.

If there was a kernel panic search for "kernel panic" on the logs dir:

```
grep -r "kernel panic" /var/log
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting that it is a hardware problem.

Comment: The computer shutdown very well could have been a hardware problem. Sometimes it is a toddler problem. (My two year old loves the shiny blue power button)

Comment: I had a room mate who was an electricity nazi. So I set up wake-on-lan.

Comment: My hardware problem ended up being a bad CyberPower UPS.