# Why did my PC shut off last nght and how do I find out if it was a sensor alarm?

Tags: shutdown, log

I tried following all of the answers to [Which log will tell me why my computer shut down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24628/which-log-will-tell-me-why-my-computer-shut-down) but all I did was find a messages.1 file which had old messages (3 month old). Other than I found the logs of my own sudo grep commands and that was it.

My best guess is it shut off when something got too hot but how can I be sure?

NB: I have next to no real idea what I am doing with the likes of grep and cat and could easily be getting it all wrong. Log files are not exactly home turf either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite generic question that it's hard to say what going on.

However that approach you mention instructs to check last logs. You have to be too wise about reading the logs, not just `grep`ing for specific words like `kernel panic`, that's really limits your chance the resolve the problem.

Examples:

- PC have power loss, there may be some errors on file system (check with `fsck`) and No lines on the log inform about normal shut down (ex: no services stopping ...
- Check for other related words may help: error, err, kill, warning, alert...
- Some `grep` flags may help much to get the event timing/sequence

  `-e` add another pattern to the query
  `-n` show the line number
  `-A` show lines after match
  `-B` show lines before match
  `-r` search recursively in a folder
  `-i` case insensitive

Another approach that could work only on reproducible problem. To verify your assumption about high temp. You can make a script that generate a log by monitoring the temperature. Check `acpitool`...